# Shiny Server on AWS not viewable on Chrome behind firewall

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, shiny-server, rstudio-server

Hello Shiny / sysadmin / AWS gurus:

I have Shiny Server running on an Ubuntu AWS instance here:
http://54.163.27.74:3838/

I followed this [R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/shiny-server-on-aws/) to get it set up, with custom TCP rules for 3838 (Shiny) and 8787 (RStudio).

It was not viewable when I tried to access at work, where some firewall seems to be in effect. So I followed the advice [here](https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#shiny-user-perms) to listen on port 80, putting this in the nginx config file:

```
location /shiny/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
}
```

It works, and my server is viewable here:
http://54.163.27.74/shiny/

Super! However, trying it at work, now it is viewable on IE, but not Chrome! On Chrome, I can see the Shiny app I am building, but it is greyed-out and not usable.

Any ideas? Can I do something else with the config file to make sure it would be viewable for all my potential users? Do I need to learn how to set up an SSL certificate or something? Thanks.